# Implementing "is open now" filter for the list of venues in web app

Tags: python, mysql, web.py

I need to implement "is open now" filter for my website that lists venues, but I don't know where to start. My website is implemented using Python, webpy, MySQL database.

I have to store the opening hours for every venue and select venues that are open now.

An example of opening hours: "Works from 9:30am to 11pm on weekdays, 11am to 11pm on weekend", or "Works round the clock excluding 6am to 7am".

Opening hours may be different for every day of week, day can have more than one interval of time, and I need to hack in exceptions for specific holidays.

Any tips/suggestions on the interface, data schema and query are welcome.

UPD: I have managed to come up with this solution, is it ok?

```
from dateutil.relativedelta import *
from dateutil.rrule import *
from datetime import *
from date import *

# venue can have many rules
hours_start = 23
minutes_start = 30
hours_end = 13  # if time_end is less than time_start then it ends next day
minutes_end = 30
days_of_week = (TH)

hours_diff = hours_end - hours_start
minutes_diff = minutes_end - minutes_start

if hours_diff < 0 or hours_diff == 0 and minutes_diff < 0:
    hours_diff += 24

datetime_start = date.today() + relativedelta(hours=+hours_start, minutes=+minutes_start, days=-1) # Yesterday time_start
now = datetime.now()
occurrence = rrule(WEEKLY, wkst=MO, byweekday=days_of_week, dtstart=datetime_start).before(now, True)

if now <= occurrence + relativedelta(hours=hours_diff, minutes=minutes_diff):
    print "IS OPEN NOW"
```

Comment: You should avoid `from ... import *`. Better explicitely specify what you want to import.

Comment: Thanks for the correction, I will not `import *` in my final code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used an app called [django-schedule](https://github.com/bartekgorny/django-schedule) which has some similar features.

If you dig in to the source, you'll see it uses [python-dateutil](http://labix.org/python-dateutil) (see rrules) underneath.  It keeps a list of schedule rules for each event in the database.

You could use a similar tactic.  When venue-open-status is queried see if the current datetime fits inside the start/end of an occurrence provided by the venue's schedule rules.  If so, it is open.

Comment: I have implemented filter code based on your suggestion. Do you have any idea on how to set exceptions for holidays?

Comment: Simplest way would be to keep a list of major holidays and add another if statement to the code, e.g.  `if now.date() in maj_holiday_list: ven_is_open = False`

Comment: Venue can have different schedule on different holidays. I am thinking of automatically set them all closed, and if they give holidays schedule then use it instead of regular schedule.

Comment: I've marked your answer as accepted, since your rrule suggestion had helped me work it out. Thanks!